# How to change class name based on scroll position?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using reactjs and need to change the class name of a div based on scroll position. Once this div reaches the top of the page, I need to change its class. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would get the offsetTop position for your div and then compare it with scrollTop, if it satisfies your condition, you would set a state which in turn would set the className.

Sample code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    style: null
  };

  handleScroll = e => {
    if (e.target.scrollTop >= this.bbox.offsetTop) {
      this.setState({
        className: "something",
        divStyle: { backgroundColor: "orange" }
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div onScroll={this.handleScroll} style={styles}>
        <Ipsum />
        <Ipsum />
        <br />
        <div
          className={this.state.className}
          style={this.state.divStyle}
          ref={ref => (this.bbox = ref)}
        >
          HelloWorld
        </div>
        <br />
        <Ipsum />
        <Ipsum />
        <Ipsum />
        <Ipsum />
        <Ipsum />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> P.S. However unlike the sample code, you need to make sure that you
> are not setting the state everytime, for performance reasons.

[**Working DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/2z5vk1rprp)